# Trim part of title. Possible bug?

Tags: titles

I have a title field with value: "Nobel Participatie Portefeuille".

On my template I want to trim the word "Nobel", You can do this with twig trim.

**so this is my code:**

{{ entry.title | trim('Nobel ') }}

But my output is "Nobel Cashflow Portefeui" (missing "lle")

Other words work normal.

Answer (score 2):

So this would be a better solution:

{{ entry.title|replace('/^Nobel /', '') }}

Thanks for the support Craft!

Comment: I was going to comment and tell you that would be a better solution, but that wasn't the question you asked you Twitter. ;)